# vulkan - why a transition command needs an old layout information

Tags: transition, vulkan

Why an old layout information is needed for setting a new layout for an image.

As far as I understand, when setting an image layout, it became in specific memory arrangement tend for optimal need. So the new layout is not dependent on what was before. A memory layout for transfer reading (VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL) is always the same and it doesn't matter what layout was before, isn't it?

But even if the old layout information is needed for transition operation (because of some reason) - still, GPU hardware/driver knows the electronics circuits condition (memory layout in this case), so why do we need to give it an information it knows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A memory layout for transfer reading (VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL) is always the same and it doesn't matter what layout was before, isn't it?

It does, if you want to convert it from the previous layout without losing the data. Otherwisely you indeed can use `oldLayout=VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED`.

> still, GPU hardware/driver knows the electronics circuits condition (memory layout in this case)

It's not "electronic circuit". Potentially it's just a haystack of bits in RAM.

Anyway. One paradigm of Vulkan is that it tries not to enforce memoization. Specifically it will often not remember state that is not part of `vkCreate*`. I think there is some functional programming influence...

Comment: A re-thinking: if giving an old layout is just a matter of keeping data, it would be enough to give a boolean parameter - if true, keep data when giving new layout, if fasle, we dont care about losing data -  so still, what the old layout information gives here?

Comment: @audi02 Layout transition can be something like a copy. You cannot copy if you do not know how to address the source memory.

Comment: @audi02 where are you going to keep that boolean? Putting it next to the image data is tricky because now you need extra allocated memory on the gpu, putting it in RAM, well now you have to keep things synchronized between vram state and ram state and you may as well delegate that to the user program

Comment: Also some transitions will end up as a nop, knowing so you miss an optimization if you don't pass the previous layout

Comment: @ratchetfreak He probably meant `VkBool32 oldLayout` parameter to the pipeline barrier instead of specifying specific layout.

Comment: @audi02 the layout is how the data is positioned in memory - e.g. interleaved/deinterleaved (its more complicated than that). If you don't know the layout, then you(driver) don't know which bytes belong to what pixel. And if you don't know that, how can you do _anything useful_ with it? We assume that driver doesn't remember this kind of state.